# Python discord bot : get last pinned message in a channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot with Python and I would like to create a command making the bot fetch the last pinned message in the channel where the command is executed in order to retrieved the mentions in that pinned message (for further use).

However I cannot find any command allowing the bot to do that...

Any help? Thanks x)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`Client.pins_from`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.pins_from) (async branch) or [`TextChannel.pins`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.TextChannel.pins) (rewrite branch).  I believe that the lists those coroutines return should be in order, oldest pins first, but I'm not sure.  If they are, this would looks like

```
pins = await client.pins_from(channel)  # or await channel.pins()
last_pin = pins[-1]
last_pin_mentions = last_pin.mentions
```